# Best way to build a wave classification system

Tags: neural-network, classification

I want to make a classifier for waves such as following:

[image]

Above image is from: http://www.invisiblesbook.com/equal-temperament-tuning/

I believe, I will have to extract features from raw input using FFT or some other method and subject that to a CNN. What is the best way to go about building classifier for such waves? I am not particularly asking about neural-networks; any other method which is accurate and fast will also be of help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't work in this field, however, recently I have read a magazine article [(in German)](https://www.heise.de/ct/ausgabe/2018-21-Wie-Shazam-Songs-erkennt-4170204.html) about this. The article explained how  one of the most well-known companies who does this, Shazam, works.

Building a spectrogram, hashing, ???, indexing.

- Video, 8:50: [How Shazam Developed Their Signature, Awesome Algorithm | Shazam Founder Chris Barton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O_iv702jj90)
- [Whitepaper](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf), from 2003, 7 pages, very technical
- github repo from an open-source implementation: https://github.com/itspoma/audio-fingerprint-identifying-python See the READme file for more links

Answer (score 1):

These waveforms are too beautiful for practice. In practice you get much more complicated waveforms and [frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_analysis) and/or [time-frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet) analysis can be helpful for your case. If not you may consider more sophisticated features.

To start, get familiar with existing [terminology, pre-processing and feature extraction methods](http://www.iro.umontreal.ca/~pift6080/H09/documents/presentations/xavier_bello_tutorial.pdf) as music processing has been studied for a long time (you may follow a former professor of mine [Meinard Müller](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=uggxDWIAAAAJ&hl=en) for deeper insight). I strongly propose to follow confirmed feature extraction methods as effective features for classifying special signals (speech, music, biological signals, etc.) are already out there.

I do not think that Neural Networks are necessary here. Of course they are effective methods but in many situations, a simpler classifier (e.g. KNN on reduced number of features) work, however I suggest to follow those literatures as I am not a music analysis expert.

I would go like this:

### Approach 1

- Extract frequency/time-frequency features and try dimensionality reduction methods to visualize them and check if classes are well-separated. If so, you simply use a classifier (RandomForest, NaiveBayes, etc.) for classification. If not you may use more complicated time-series analysis.

### Approach 2

- Try [state-space reconstruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space) to extract the nonlinear behavior of your time-series. Via this analysis you can build [Recurrence Plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_plot) and [Recurrence Networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/0908.3447) which most probably help your analysis. They offer [variety of features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_quantification_analysis#RQA_measures).